# Multiple Events onChange with if/else statement

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, slider

I'm using a bootstrap form slider from 1-5 to describe the condition of something from good - bad. On the slider change, I want it to envoke two functions; one to change the number in the state, and then one to identify the correct text to go with the number and display it as the user slides the slider. I've tried a few different variations of this, but nothing seems to work. Would also welcome other ways of forming the functions or state all together. Thanks in advance.

```
class ConditionSlider extends Component {
     constructor (props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             condition: 1
         };
     };

render() {

const slideCalls = (e) => {
    slideChangeState(e);
    conditionText(e)
    };

const slideChangeState = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        condition: e
        })
    }

let spanText;
const conditionText = (e) => {
    if(e === '1' ) {
        spanText = <div>Very Poor</div>
    } else if (e === '2') {
        spanText = <div>Poor</div>
    } else if (e === '3') {
        spanText = <div>Okay</div>
    } else if (e === '4') {
        spanText = <div>Good</div>
    } else if (e === '5') {
        spanText = <div>Excellent</div>
    }
}


console.log(this.state.condition)

return (
    <div className="slide-class">
    <RangeSlider 
        value={this.state.condition}
        onChange={e => slideCalls(e.target.value)}
        min={1}
        max={5}
        step={1}
        size='sm'
        tooltip='off'
        variant='primary'
        />
        <p>{this.spanText}</p>
        <p>{spanText}</p>
    </div>
    )}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify several things first to make it work. First, the render function should not contain those two functions. Then, you could have an object that contains the numbers as keys (1 to 5) and the string that correlates with that number (Poor, excelent, etc.) so you don't fallback to a large `if...else` statement.

So leaving it as this:

```
const RANGES = {
  1: "Very Poor",
  2: "Poor",
  3: "Okay",
  4: "Good",
  5: "Excellent",
}

class ConditionSlider extends Component {
     constructor (props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             condition: 1
         };
     };
slideCalls(e) {
    slideChangeState(e);
    conditionText(e)
    };

slideChangeState(e) {
    this.setState({
        condition: e
        })
    }

render() {

return (
    <div className="slide-class">
    <RangeSlider 
        value={this.state.condition}
        onChange={e => slideCalls(e.target.value)}
        min={1}
        max={5}
        step={1}
        size='sm'
        tooltip='off'
        variant='primary'
        />
        <p>{RANGES[this.state.condition]}</p> // removed <div> here since you cant have a div inside a <p> element. I mean, you could but it would display an error in the console
        <p>{spanText}</p>
    </div>
    )}
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This did work for me, I just had to remove the 'slideCalls' function altogether and just call 'this.slideChangeState(e.target.value)' instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm coding this blind, but this is how I'd handle this situation.  If you're using state to manage the value of the slider then you ,ight as well use state to hold the text value too.

I've moved the functions outside of the render method, and as `slideChangeState` requires access to `this` I've bound it in the constructor.

I hope this helps - never used this control before

```
class ConditionSlider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            condition: 1,
            spanText: "Very Poor"
        };
        this.slideChangeState = this.slideChangeState.bind(this);
    };

    slideChangeState(value) {
        var spanText = conditionText(value);
        this.setState({
            condition: value,
            spanText: spanText
        })
    };

    conditionText(value) {
        switch (value) {
            case 1:
                return "Very Poor";
            case 2:
                return "Poor";
            case 3:
                return "Okay";
            case 4:
                return "Good";
            case 5:
                return "Excellent"
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="slide-class">
                <RangeSlider
                    value={this.state.condition}
                    onChange={e => slideCalls(e.target.value)}
                    min={1}
                    max={5}
                    step={1}
                    size='sm'
                    tooltip='off'
                    variant='primary'
                />
                <p>{this.state.spanText}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: Hmmm... I've tried to switch some things around here, but I think it keeps getting tripped up at var spanText = conditionText(value). Can you assign a variable to a function?

Comment: ah whoops. Probably should have been '= this.conditionText(value)'. Glad you got a working solution though